# TQDM colored progress bar printing on multiple lines

Tags: python, tqdm

I'm not sure why my TQDM progress bar is splitting into multiple rows when I add color using the `bar_format` option. It seems to have to do with the number of iterations as well, because when I run the same code with only 10 iterations instead of 1389 it does not split (see images). Also, when I run the same code without modifying the color of the bar, it works fine.

[image: Problem]

[image: Fewer iterations]

[image: No color]

```
from tqdm import tqdm
from colorama import Fore

dnames = [...]  # List of directories
cmap = [  # List of colors, same length as `dnames`
    '\x1b[38;5;231m',
    '\x1b[38;5;194m',
    '\x1b[38;5;151m',
    '\x1b[38;5;114m',
    '\x1b[38;5;71m',
    '\x1b[38;5;29m',
    '\x1b[38;5;22m',
    '\x1b[38;5;22m',
    '\x1b[38;5;22m',
    '\x1b[38;5;22m'
    # ...may include many more colors
]

# Initialize progress bar and color variable
pbar = tqdm(dnames, unit='dir')
current_color = None

for i, dname in enumerate(dnames):

    # Update color of pbar if different from last iteration
    if current_color != cmap[i]:
        pbar.bar_format = "{l_bar}%s{bar}%s{r_bar}" % (cmap[i], Fore.RESET)
        current_color = cmap[i]

    # For loop body goes here

    # Update pbar
    pbar.update(1)

pbar.close()
```

Answer (score 11):

Your code is working perfectly fine for me, the other answer about your `tqdm` version might help. TL;DR You need to update

---

For anyone wondering, here's how to set the color of the bar:

```py
from tqdm import tqdm
from time import sleep

for i in tqdm(range(100), colour="red"):
    sleep(0.001)
```

valid choices of colour: `[hex (#00ff00), BLACK, RED, GREEN, YELLOW, BLUE, MAGENTA, CYAN, WHITE]`

Documentation:

> https://tqdm.github.io/docs/tqdm/#format_meter

Answer (score 2):

Fixed in [tqdm>=4.41.1](https://tqdm.github.io/releases/#v4411-2020-01-05).

Also on a related note, the latest version [tqdm>=4.50.0](https://tqdm.github.io/releases/#v4500-2020-09-28) adds a `colour` argument to make this easier