# New color terminal prograss bar in pip

Tags: python

I find the new version pip(package installer for Python) has a colorful progress bar to show the downloading progress. How can I do that?

Like this:
[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58328625/tqdm-colored-progress-bar-printing-on-multiple-lines

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/how-do-i-print-colored-text-to-the-terminal-in-python

Comment: @404pio, it's cool, but I want a more fancy bar like the pip has :D. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 12, accepted):

pip itself is using the [rich](https://pypi.org/project/rich/) package!
In particular, their [progress bar docs](https://rich.readthedocs.io/en/latest/progress.html) show this example:

```python
from rich.progress import track

for n in track(range(n), description="Processing..."):
    do_work(n)
```

Answer (score 3):

```py
import time 
from rich.progress import track

for n in track(range(20), description="Processing..."):
    time.sleep(n)
```

[image]

Rich is installed with latest pip, but incase you are missing it:

```bash
pip install rich
```

Answer (score 1):

The following simple code uses pip own progress bar controls.

```
import time

from pip._internal.cli.progress_bars import get_download_progress_renderer


if __name__ == "__main__":
    chunks = []
    b = get_download_progress_renderer(bar_type="on",size=100)
    for i in range(100):
        chunks.append(range(i))
        for bb in b(chunks):
            time.sleep(.1)
```

The output will look something like this...
[image]